# TreeMenu with self Referencing and nested Menu

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a need to create a **TreeMenu** using `NHibernate`.

Here is what i cameup with:

```
public class CategoryMap : ClassMap<Category>
{
    public CategoryMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.AppId);
        Map(x => x.Title);
        Map(x => x.MaxDepth).Default("3");
        Map(x => x.IsActive);
        References(x => x.Parent).LazyLoad().Column("ParentId");

        HasMany(x => x.ChildrenNodes)
            .LazyLoad()
            .KeyColumn("ParentId")
            .Cascade.All();

        Table("Category");
    }
}

public class Category : Node
{
    public virtual string AppId { get; set; }
    public override string Title { get; set; }
    public override int MaxDepth { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Category> ChildrenNodes { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Node
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public abstract string Title { get; set; }
    public abstract int MaxDepth { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my testing code:

```
[Test]
    public void CreateTableInDb()
    {

        using (var db = new FileDatabase(DbFileLocation, true))
        {
            var categoryMenu = new Category
            {
                AppId = "1",
                MaxDepth = 3,
                IsActive = true,
                Title = "Services"
            };

            db.Create(categoryMenu);


            categoryMenu.ChildrenNodes = new List<Category>
            {
                new Category
                {
                    Title = "SubService-Level1",
                    Parent = categoryMenu,
                }
            };

            db.Update(categoryMenu);
        }
    }
```

When i look into the table it's creating i have only one row,
with empty `ParentId` column.

How can i fix it and what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you try save Child node separately before add it to the parent?

Comment: My solution work as is, but it's not really good when i use repository it's flattens the query to one list.

Answer (score 0):

- first you'll missing `.Inverse()` on the hasmany. As it stands it will save and update the parentId twice
- all collections should be readonly. NHibernate will replace them with tracking and lazyloading collections which you are throwing away. Change the code to

  ```
  public class Category : Node
  {
      public Category()
      {
          // best practice so that nobody has to null check the collection
          ChildrenNodes = new List<Category>();
      }
      public virtual IList<Category> ChildrenNodes { get; private set; }

      public void Add(Category subcategory)
      {
          subcategory.Parent = this;
          ChildrenNodes.Add(subcategory);
      }
  }

  // in testcode
  categoryMenu.Add(new Category { Title = "SubService-Level1" });
  ```